# Evitar superposición de secciones de un HTML usando CSS

Tags: html, css

buenas noches amigos, verán estoy haciendo un sitio separado en tres secciones principales, el formato se repite en otras 2 páginas.

```
[Menu]
[Contenido]
[Pie]
```

Usando un css les di formato a cada sección, sin embargo, al insertar un iframe con una ubicación en mi segunda página, lo que se encuentra en [Contenido] se superpone a lo que tengo en  mi [Footer] sin respetar el tamaño variante del [Contenido].

En mi tercera página si está respetando el tamaño de lo que hay en [Contenido], siendo aún más grande que lo que se encuentra en mi segunda página.

Así es como tengo mi CSS:

```
contenido {
    margin-top:6em;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background-color:#5A5A5A;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:1em;
    width:80%;
    border: solid #FFFFFF;
}
pie {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    width:80%;
    background-color:#840002;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-align:center;
    border: solid #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
        }
```

Espero alguien pueda decirme que es lo que estoy implementando y una forma de corregirlo, sólo es ese pequeño detalle,  de ante mano gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta no utilizar float o position:absolute si no quieres que se superponga el contenido.

Te recomiendo utilizar Normalize como base en tu web para el css:
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Prueba con este código y utiliza solo lo que necesites:

```css
section {
    margin:6em auto 0 auto; /* centra section */
    background-color:#5A5A5A;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:1em;
    width:80%;
    border: solid #FFFFFF;
}
  
footer {
    margin:6em auto 0 auto; /* centra section */
    width:80%;
    background-color:#840002;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-align:center;
    border: solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Your Website</title>
</head>

<body>

 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>Menú</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 <section>
  Contenido
 </section>

 <footer>
  Pie
 </footer>

</body>

</html>
```